# Change object.color property of multiple objects at a time without scripting?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, interface

Is it possible to change the object.color property of multiple objects at the same time without scripting?

For a lot of stuff in the properties tab, even modifiers, you can hold down ALT while toggling a certain property and all selected objects will be affected, but I can't find a way to do it for the object.color property:

[image]

I'm aware you can also use materials and just link materials, but the question is about object.color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>ALT</kbd> multiple-property editing mechanic does not work if you click directly the *Color Wheel*, however it does work if you're tweaking the Red, Green or Blue channels of the color.

Note that you will have to set the display to *RGB* instead of the default *HSV* beforehand. It does not matter if you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> when clicking on the color field, but you do have to press it when scrubbing or before inputting a value in one of the channels.

Illustration :

[image]

Also note that if you are scrubbing a channel field, the value of that channel in all the selected objects will get relatively incremented by the scrubbed value, but if they start with a different color, their color won't always match when you finish scrubbing.

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this will help a ton! Also, thanks for going so in depth.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with Blender 3.2.0 (macos)

Comment: @DevonDahon it does work on my 3.2.1 on Windows. Try updating to the latest version and make sure you are in RGB mode. Might also be a macos specific problem, might be worth making a bug report if so